# Kubernetes cronJob to call REST API using CURL with headers is failing with curl(6) : could not resolve host

Tags: curl, kubernetes, rest, request-headers

How can I trigger the restAPI[POST with header having authentication and parameter] in cronJob using kubernetes. When I create the cron and try to run it I am getting the following error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

When i replace the host with the actual rather than localhost it still gives me the error as

```
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host : xxxHostName
```

I am able to hit the curl using the command prompt as well as in the POSTMAN

Following is the cronJob which i am trying to run

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: e2em-rule-violation-job  
spec:
  schedule: "*/3 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: e2em-rule-violation-job 
            image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "curl -H \"Authorization: Basic c3lzdGVtOm1hbmFnZQ==\" -H \"InternalUser: true\" -X POST  \"http://localhost:8080/myIntegration/rest/executeScheduledTask\""
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Following is the dry run which is successful but Jobs fails when its created

```
W1006 13:35:34.443357   18304 helpers.go:535] --dry-run is deprecated and can be replaced with --dry-run=client.
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"batch/v1beta1","kind":"CronJob","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"e2em-rule-violation-job","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"concurrencyPolicy":"Allow","failedJobsHistoryLimit":1,"jobTemplate":{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"args":["/bin/sh","-ec","curl -H \"Authorization: Basic c3lzdGVtOm1hbmFnZQ==\" -H \"InternalUser: true\" -X POST  \"http://localhost:8080/myIntegration/rest/executeScheduledTask\""],"image":"curlimages/curl:7.72.0","name":"e2em-rule-violation-job"}],"restartPolicy":"OnFailure"}}}},"schedule":"*/3 * * * *","successfulJobsHistoryLimit":3}}
  name: e2em-rule-violation-job
  namespace: default
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - 'curl -H "Authorization: Basic c3lzdGVtOm1hbmFnZQ==" -H "InternalUser:
              true" -X POST  "http://localhost:8080/myIntegration/rest/executeScheduledTask"'
            image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0
            name: e2em-rule-violation-job
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/3 * * * *'
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"curl -H \"Authorization: Basic c3lzdGVtOm1hbmFnZQ==\" -H \"InternalUser: true\" -X POST  \"http://localhost:8080/myIntegration/rest/executeScheduledTask\""
```

The problem in your case is in the above curl. Look, you are trying to curl non-existent address. Whats happening once you run cronjob?

1. k8s creates `cronjob` `e2em-rule-violation-job`
2. `cronjob` `e2em-rule-violation-job` CREATES `POD`
3. curl command is trying to run exactly inside from this POD

You POD doesnt know what the `localhost:8080` is. You pod has absolutelly  another localcost comparing to where your app is running...This address is not exposed, you pod cant have access to it. Plus `image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0` [dockerfile](https://github.com/curl/curl-docker/blob/master/alpine/latest/Dockerfile) doesnt have port 8080 exposed..

What you can do for test is to

1. create normal deployment with the curl pod, lets say `NEWCURLPOD`
2. connect to `NEWCURLPOD` and execute your initial command you wanted to run. Example: `kubectl exec -ti {NEWCURLPOD} -n {PROPER_NAMESPACE} -- curl blablabla`

If that will not work - check dns.
If your app is running inside the same cluster - you should properly expose its service to reach the target, but for sure this is not `localhost:8080`

Dry run..

> Following is the dry run which is successful but Jobs fails when its
> created

While running dry-run  - it only check and preview the object, it should not execute curl there - as a result you see it completes successfully.

Comment: Hello, but it works fine if I don’t pass the header . The issue which I have mentioned comes only when I add the header